# Mariadb tables empty after mysqldump restore

Tags: mariadb, backup, restore

I am having a problem that has left me stumped. I have two database servers, one is replicating to the other via ssh tunnel (without problems). Both are running MariaDB 10.11.4 on Debian 12. I am doing a database backup nightly on the slave with the command

```
mysqldump --opt -uroot -p$PASS $DB | gzip > backup.$DATE.dmp.gz
```

I am trying to restore the backup on the master to a temporary database using the command

```
gunzip -c backup.$DATE.dmp.gz | mysql -uroot -p$PASS temp
```

The restore appears to work fine, there is no error message and there is no error in syslog. However, upon accessing the database "temp", all the tables have been created, but are empty (0 rows). When trying to manually insert a row in one of the tables, that works fine, it then has 1 rows. The server has plenty of disk space, so that should not be a problem.

When trying the same restore on the slave or on a different server, the database is properly restored and contains all the expected data, so the backup file appears to be fine.

These are the DB settings on the master that differ from the slave:

```
[mysqld]
server_id=4
sql_mode = "ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
character-set-server = utf8mb4
skip-character-set-client-handshake
init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
init_connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
log_bin                = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days       = 4
max_binlog_size        = 100M
binlog_do_db           = tax
```

(on the slave, these are all left on default except the server_id).

This restore used to work without problems until a recent move of the main DB to a different server with a newer Debian version (and likely newer MariaDB version).

I have tried restoring backups of two entirely different database schemas on the master DB server, one of them was correctly restored, the other had the same behavior. One of the possible differences is that the databases that could not be restored both contain a lot of binary data in blobs.

Any ideas what could cause this or how to narrow it down?

Edit:

I now narrowed it down. Configuration:

```
[mysqld]
server_id=3
log_bin                = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
binlog_do_db = tax
```

Test file:

```
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `benutzer`;
CREATE TABLE `benutzer` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `vorname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `nachname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10433 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `benutzer` VALUES (1,'Arno','Schäfer');
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
```

If I set the server to this configuration and try to load this test file into database "temp", no row is inserted. If I remove the binlog_do_db line in the config, the problem goes away. If I remove either of the FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS or UNIQUE_CHECKS lines, the problem goes away. I would assume I stumbled upon a bug in MariaDB 10.11.4, unless someone could explain how a binlog_do_db line can prevent an insert in a different database. If I am not mistaken, binlog_do_db should prevent the INSERT from being logged in the binlog, but not from being executed in the first place, right?

Comment: you basically need to have the same version, for taht to work, maybe if you know your version you can check if there is a upgrade possible

Comment: I am not sure what version you talk about? As I said, I am running MariaDB 10.11.4 on both servers, so there should be no compatibility issues there. Also, I was under the impression that mysqldumps are pretty much version-independent, but that may not apply across all versions.

Comment: you said in your question newer version of  myriadb was on your second server

Comment: you should open a ssh between both servers and replicate the data

Comment: @nbk: Sorry, that was a misunderstanding. I meant I probably had a different mariadb version before (whatever was the version on debian 11), when everything worked. Now, with 10.11.4 on both servers, it no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was indeed a bug in MariaDB, it was fixed in Version 10.11.6 (among others).